# How do I get my iPhone and iPad to automatically search changes of IP addresses with WiFi extenders

Tags: wifi

I have two WiFi extenders and when I move within the range of each extender or back to the router the IP addresses change but my iPhone and iPad don't apply the changes. I have to manually switch off WiFi and restart it to get the device to find the right address.

Comment: Try the Eero mesh wifi system: https://Eero.com

Comment: I'm tempted to think that if the IP address is changing, then you have more than one DHCP server - which is not a good thing. Make your main router the only server.

Comment: Do you have bonafide *range extenders* or wifi routers *acting* as range extenders?  If the latter, did you turn off DHCP on them?  Your IP lease shouldn't be lost unless you have it set for a very small window.

Comment: Personally, I always wire to my APs, all back to one switch, one router. Takes the guesswork out of it & keeps the overall connection speed as high as possible. though I understand it's not always practicable, in which case some kind of power line/homeplug system may be next best.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a tech virgin, so what's an AP please? There's one router and two extenders, both TP Link.300mbps plug into wall socket versions.

Comment: @RichardWalker an Access Point (i.e. wifi range extender). But really, try Eero. It'll fix all of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your devices (iPad, iPod) are not disconnecting from the first AP and connecting to the *extender* AP because the signal is still *too good* for it to disconnect from.

One of the best ways I have found to create a much more reliable wireless infrastructure is to **turn down the transmission power** of the WAP.

In basic terms, this lowers the distance that a good signal will get to your device meaning your device will begin looking for a new WAP sooner.  The downside to this is that you will need more extenders.

The other way is to invest in "Enterprise grade" WAPs that have "handoff" built into the controller - this allows you to specify what the threshold is before the WAP "kicks off" the client and forces it to to search for another WAP.

Comment: Additionally, make the device IP addresses on the DHCP server static, so nothing changes except which AP it's using. That works fairly well here, for a couple of fairly standard consumer APs. I also have the power turned down on the 'slow' one & full on the 'good' one, to bias it; the 'slow' one just fills a hole the good one can't reach properly.

Comment: One benefit  I have seen to *turning down the power* is that the APs seem to last longer - at least that's my perception.

Comment: You mean actual time to failure? I don't think I've ever had one fail - I periodically upgrade for newer protocols, but haven't had one just curl up its toes on me yet. :) There's sense in it, though, working at less than full capacity == longer lifespan.

Comment: I used to go through a wifi router about once per year.  The wifi would just fail.  Router/switch portion would work, but wifi was toast.  I

Comment: Ouch... expensive :/ I actually don't have a wifi/router - well, it's dumbed down to pure modem mode & I hang a Sophos UTM off the back of it. If I could afford Sophos APs that might be nice, but as it is I just have a couple of dedicated APs I wire to, one DLink [not recommended] one Cisco [nice]

Comment: I am slowly transitioning out of my consumer grade stuff...I went pfSense on an old Dell and as the wifi routers fail, I go Ubiquiti.